# Stack builder for postgresql does not list local installation

Tags: windows, postgresql

As per the pgAdmin site, the pgAgent can be downloaded using EDB's Stackbuilder.
I have postgres 15 running and pgAdmin 4 can connect to it and there is a database and everyone's happy..

However, I am trying to download pgAgent. The Stackbuilder wizard downloaded for Windows x64 does not list the local installation to select. It does show remote and selecting that does not list pgAgent.
So I am stuck and googling around without any luck..

[image: Stack Builder 4.2.1 not listing local postgresql installation]

Comment: Here is the source code of the stack builder and that first page of the wizard. It seems like its reading some keys from the registry. I have added some of the keys and values in the registry, but still no lock. Not too fluent with c++, so might would have missed something..
https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/stackbuilder/blob/master/IntroductionPage.cpp#L136

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install PostgreSQL database along with Stackbuilder. That fixed the issue with the listing of the local installation.

Now that it lists, checking the registry shows the following entries for key:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Services\postgresql-x64-15

[image: Registry key for postgres stackbuilder]